# How to stop GeometryReader changing value when keyboard opens

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm struggling to find documentation to support this but it seems as though the values of

GeometryReader.size.width & height change when the keyboard opens. This can be proven through something like:

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        GeometryReader { g in
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width:g.size.width/2,height:g.size.height/20)
                
                    TextField(...)
                    }
        }
    }
```

which shows the rectangle resizing when the keyboard opens by clicking on the textfield.

How would I prevent this from happening? I want to specify the frame size relative to screen size to support many screen sizes...

Comment: You cannot. The `GeometryReader` reads free space of parent container, not a whole screen, so when keyboard appeared free space becomes smaller on keyboard frame, so GeometryReader provides dynamically smaller frame, as intentionally designed. Would you instead describe point of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a geometry reader to know the screen's size. you can get screen's dimensions using `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` and `UIScreen.main.bounds.height`.
Note width always shows the horizontal-dimension's size, and height always shows the vertical one (incase of screen rotation)

Comment: However, you need it to know the actual size of the app. Specially when fullscreen is not enforced and 2 apps can be open at the same time dividing the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to the GeometryReader:

```
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
```

Comment: does not work for me, it still regenerates its subviews